# How to refresh by pulling down the items?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

there are lots of answers for this question, but, all of them as I see, are about getting old items at the bottom.

this solution:

```
void resultList_ItemRealized(object sender, ItemRealizationEventArgs e)
{
    if (!_viewModel.IsLoading && resultList.ItemsSource != null && resultList.ItemsSource.Count >= _offsetKnob)
    {
        if (e.ItemKind == LongListSelectorItemKind.Item)
        {
            if ((e.Container.Content as TwitterSearchResult).Equals(resultList.ItemsSource[resultList.ItemsSource.Count - _offsetKnob]))
            {
                _viewModel.LoadPage(_searchTerm, _pageNumber++);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

is about getting items as you scroll down.

How can I get fresh new content at top (not more old content at the bottom)? how can I know if user is scrolling up the `LongListSelector`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two posts for accomplishing this for the ListBox in Windows Phone 7 (which you have tagged) and will also work for Windows Phone 8

http://sharpgis.net/post/2011/04/03/RefreshBox-for-Windows-Phone-7.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jasongin/archive/2011/04/13/pull-down-to-refresh-a-wp7-listbox-or-scrollviewer.aspx

Both state to set

```
ScrollViewer.ManipulationMode ="Control"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't rely on `ItemRealized` being fired. You need to add a listener on the `ManipulationDelta` event on `LongListSelector`. If the delta is negative the user scrolled up.

**EDIT**

I just remembered that Microsoft made some changed to `LongListSelector (LLS)` in `Windows Phone 8` which means that it isn't possible to get in which direction the list is scrolling.

A workaround is to put the `LLS` in a `ScrollViewer`. Then set the `Height` property of the `LLS` to **Auto**. That way it is the `ScrollViewer` that scrolls and not the `LLS`. Then add a listener on the `ScrollViewer's` `VerticalOffset`.

```
private double _scrollingFrom;

ScrollViewer.Loaded += (sender, args) => VisualStateHelper.HookEvent<ScrollViewer>(ScrollViewer, "ScrollStates", scrollHandler);

private void scrollHandler(object sender, VisualStateChangedEventArgs e) {
    if (e.NewState.Name.Equals("NotScrolling")) {
        if (ScrollViewer.VerticalOffset < _scrollingFrom) {
            // Scrolled up
        } else {
            // Scrolled down
        }
    } else {
        _scrollingFrom = ScrollViewer.VerticalOffset;
    }
}
```

See [here](https://github.com/Miista/visual-state-helper/blob/master/VisualStateHelper.cs) for VisualStateHelper

Comment: I see it just occurs horizontally

Comment: What do you mean "occurs horizontally"?

Comment: I mean it doesn't occur when I scroll down or up the LLS

Comment: What about `ManipulationStarted` or `ManipulationCompleted`?

Comment: will that help in my case?

Comment: Are you using `Windows Phone 7` or `Windows Phone 8`?