# How to know if an item is visible to user?

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

please look at this:

```
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer>
        <Grid Background="Red" Width="50" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,-50,0,0"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

here the red grid is not visible because of its margin. but when user pulls down, it will be visible on the screen.

How can I know when it is visible? thanks.

(It's a WP8 app, if that matters)

Comment: if the ScrollViewer VerticalOffset >= 50 would mean its visible

Comment: thanks @sa_ddam213 . Is there a way to know it is scrolling?

Comment: You should subscribe to [`ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.scrollchanged.aspx) event.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek surprisingly it is not supported in windows phone

Comment: Are you trying to implement pull to refresh? Have you seen [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jasongin/archive/2011/04/13/pull-down-to-refresh-a-wp7-listbox-or-scrollviewer.aspx) or [this](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/TwitterSearch-Windows-b7fc4e5e) might help. Telerik has a [good solution](http://www.telerik.com/help/windows-phone/raddataboundlistbox-features-pulltorefresh.html)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to refresh by pulling down the items?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20037629/how-to-refresh-by-pulling-down-the-items)

Answer (score 0):

This method might come handy for you.

```
private bool IsUserVisible(FrameworkElement element, FrameworkElement container)
{
    if (!element.IsVisible)
        return false;

    Rect bounds = element.TransformToAncestor(container).TransformBounds(new Rect(0.0, 0.0, element.ActualWidth, element.ActualHeight));
    Rect rect = new Rect(0.0, 0.0, container.ActualWidth, container.ActualHeight);
    return rect.Contains(bounds.TopLeft) || rect.Contains(bounds.BottomRight);
}
```